# Get local port when using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android, http, sockets

I am using `HttpURLConnection` to connect to remote HTTP sever.

Is it possible to get the local opened port for this HTTP connection?

Comment: For what purpose? There's nothing useful you can do wih it.

Comment: @EJP - We can check if the requests are being sent on the same connection. For example, NTLM authentication requires all request-response that are part of the NTLM authentication handshake to be sent on the same connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is **not** possible with [Android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html) on Android phones without root rights.